How to trigger a webhook in Dialogflow CX when a user hangs up?
I am using Dialogflow CX to build a bot, and I need an event to trigger a webhook when the user hangs up (i.e., abandons the conversation). Is there any way to achieve this?
I need the webhook to be triggered automatically when the conversation ends unexpectedly during phone calls.

What Communication platform are you using?
I.e. Twilio

I'm using genesys Cloud

There is another possibility. You can configure pub/sub notifications for conversation profiles via https://agentassist.cloud.google.com if the integration uses the CCAI integration which Genesys Cloud does use and they already work for the virtual agent stage, not only agent assist.
Check the conversation lifecycle events for details.
